# Does Ubuntu 12.04LTS have the OpenSSL heartbleed fix?

Tags: ubuntu, security, openssl, heartbleed

Only OpenSSL 1.0.1f or later has the fix for the heartbleed exploit. So does Ubuntu 12.04LTS have the fix? We need to use 12.04LTS for reasons I won't go into, and we can't upgrade.

According to this page, it uses OpenSSL "1.0.1" (with no letter at the end of the version number):
http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libssl-dev

It has this file link on the right hand side...
[openssl_1.0.1.orig.tar.gz]

Can that .orig file tell us anything?

Does anyone know if there was actually a "1.0.1" release of OpenSSL, or if someone just chopped off the letter?

Answer (score 2):

The actual version of affected OpenSSL version in Ubuntu 12.04LTS is 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.11 and current version is 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.21 (the number at the end matters here). It's been patched a few times since and should not be affected by heartbleed bug.

Here's a link from which you can see affected version numbers in different distributions: http://heartbleed.com/

Just in case here's also changelog for OpenSSL in Ubuntu 12.04LTS: http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1-4ubuntu5.21/changelog

Fix for heartbleed is mentioned for 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12 so couple of versions back.

Answer (score 0):

A way to know this is to have a look at the Ubuntu Security Notices (USN) which are released each time a vulnerability is fixed in Ubuntu. In such case, the release of the package in which it is fixed is written.

For instance, for heartbleed, the USN was the USN-2165-1 (http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2165-1/) which states that it has been fixed in 1.0.1-4ubuntu5.12 for Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

It is possible to subscribe to such USN by emails, thanks to the ubuntu-security-announce mailing-list: https://lists.ubuntu.com/mailman/listinfo/ubuntu-security-announce

Cheers,